# Swift Core Data adding 2 extra custom cells for each object I Add

Tags: swift

I'm using Swift Xcode 6.3.2. I made a custom template cell. The app loads my template cell upon launch. I have an "add" button which uses an alert view to add a new "name" to Core Data.

Every time I add a new name the table updates and adds 2 extra template cells as well as the cell with the newly added name. It does this for each name I add. Help would be greatly appreciated! I would attach an image but I don't have reputation points to do so. I'm learning so please disregard all of the comments in my code.

At this point, I receive no errors or crashing. Thank you for helping!

```
import UIKit
import CoreData


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
//storing Person entities instead of just names so this Mutable Array is called people
//instead of names and is of NSManagedObject instead of a String
var people = [NSManagedObject]()


//Implementing the Add Name Button Action
@IBAction func addName(sender: AnyObject) {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Player Name",
            message: "Add New Player",
            preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .Default) { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        let textField = alert.textFields![0] as! UITextField

        //use saveName func to to save to Core Data
        self.saveName(textField.text)
        self.tableView.reloadData()

        //replace this line for Core Data
        //self.names.append(textField.text)
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default) { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in

    }

    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField: UITextField!) -> Void in

    }

    alert.addAction(saveAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //prints managedObjectContext to Console
    println(managedObjectContext)

    //this instantiates instances of our Core Data Entity
    let newPerson = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!) as! Person

    title = "Pitch Count"
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

// MARK: UITableViewDataSource
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return people.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return customPitcherCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)
}

func customPitcherCellAtIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> CustomPitcherListCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell") as! CustomPitcherListCell
    setPlayerNameForCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
    //setNumberOfPitchesForCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)

    return cell
}

func setPlayerNameForCell(cell:CustomPitcherListCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let person = people[indexPath.row] as! Person
    cell.playerNameOutlet.text = person.valueForKey("name") as? String
}
```

Here is the saveName func.

```
func saveName(name: String) {
    //step 1
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
    let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

    //step 2
    person.setValue(name, forKey: "name")

    //Step 3
    var error: NSError?
    if !managedObjectContext!.save(&error) {
        println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")

    }
    //Step 4
    people.append(person)
}
```

Here is the fetch request

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    deselectAllRows()
    self.tableView.reloadData()

    //Step 1
    //Creates a new fetch request using the Person Entity
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    //Step 2
    //Executes the fetch request and casts new data to an array "people"
    //if there's an error or cannot get results, this will provide a message as well.
    var error: NSError?
    let fetchedResults = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [Person]

    if let results = fetchedResults {
        people = results
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Comment: In step1 of the saveName function, use just:
`NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)`. It creates and insert new entity in one step. It should help.

Comment: Ahhh. I found the problem... Removed 1 line of code and it resolved everything. In ViewDidLoad I wrote this line of code. let newPerson = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!) as! Person

Answer (score 0):

Found where I went wrong.
I was instantiating a new instance of my core data entity under viewDidLoad. I am not using that instance but I think it would be good to do so in the future. I removed that line of code and the tableview no longer creates extra template cells. Removed "let newPerson = ...."

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //hides the menu bar when scrolling down
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true

    //prints managedObjectContext to Console
    println(managedObjectContext)

    //this instantiates instances of our Core Data Entity
    let newPerson = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!) as! Person

    title = "Pitch Count"
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```